# Spark program is not printing Hive Database or Table list

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have spark program(version 2.0) which would connect to Hive and tries to print the database list, table list and at the end it would create a new hive table('mytable') in the database 'testdata'.

Instead of printing the database list, the df.show is printing the default database name where as i am expecting to print all the databsed avaialbe on hive.

Also, when the new table is being printed program is printing message that database is not available, where as the database already exists in hive.

Here is what is being printed.

Can someone help to fix my program?

```
+------------+
|databaseName|
+------------+
|     default|
+------------+

+---------+-----------+
|tableName|isTemporary|
+---------+-----------+
+---------+-----------+


import java.io.Serializable;

//$example off:programmatic_schema$
import org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException;
//$example on:create_df$
//$example on:run_sql$
//$example on:programmatic_schema$
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
//$example on:init_session$
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class SparkLoad {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws AnalysisException { 
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .master("local") ///local 
      .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
      .getOrCreate();

    abcd(spark);

    spark.stop(); 
  }

  private static void abcd(SparkSession spark) {

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES");
        df.show(); //this should print the database list.

        Dataset<Row> dff = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES");
        dff.show(); //this should print all table list.

        spark.sql("create table testdata.mytable (text1 varchar(64), text2 varchar(64), text3 varchar(64), "
                + "link string, text4 varchar(64),text5 varchar(64),text6 varchar(64),text7 varchar(64),text8 varchar(250),"
                + "text9 varchar(250),text10 varchar(250),text11 varchar(250),text12 varchar(64),text13 varchar(64),text14 varchar(64),"
                + "text15 varchar(64),text16 varchar(64),text17 varchar(64),text18 varchar(250),text19 varchar(64),text20 varchar(64),"
                + "text21 varchar(64),text22 varchar(64),text23 varchar(64),text24 varchar(64),text25 varchar(64),text26 varchar(64),"
                + "text27 varchar(64),text28 varchar(64),text29 varchar(64),text30 varchar(64),text31 varchar(64),text32 varchar(64))"
                + " row format delimited fields terminated by '~' STORED AS TEXTFILE");

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try copying hive-site.xml to spark conf directory. Below link might help.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/how-to-access-the-hive-tables-from-spark-shell/td-p/36609

Comment: I have the hive-site.xml in conf folder of spark installation. Still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate();
```

Did you add SparkSession.enableHiveSupport() ?